# Why when the dot product of two vectors is 0 they're perpendicular?

Tags: analytic-geometry

If I have two vectors A and B and A.B=0 then A and B are perpendicular.

I would like to know why.

Thank You.

Comment: This is by definition for arbitrary inner product spaces.  If you are talking specifically about euclidian space, then note that $\langle a,b\rangle = \|a\|\|b\|\cos(\theta)$ which for nonzero $a$ and $b$ is equal to zero iff $\cos(\theta)=0$ which occurs precisely when $\theta=\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP does not mean arbitrary inner product spaces but the Euclidean space.  Also,  I am pretty sure the OP has an idea of orthogonality that is not based on scalar products

Comment: This could be answered at different levels of complexity. Very very hand wavy the dot product measures the shadow one vector casts on another.  Being perpendicular there is no shadow cast.  I am aware this is unsatisfactory as a full explanation but it may give a flavour.

Comment: I would like to know in analytic geometry

Comment: As was noted, there are several different ways to show this. Give us your definition of the scalar product so that we know which one is relevant.

Comment: https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product&ei=kxLbIxdk&lc=pt-BR&s=1&m=99&host=www.google.com.br&ts=1493600253&sig=AJsQQ1C1YKXnRnnDLxaeDamXnKufFrGzSQ I don't know really if that is what you want

Comment: I wanted the definition that *you* are starting from, not a wikipedia entry that includes several. That page that you linked answers your question, by the way.